# confusion with viariables when writing a script in ubuntu with

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a script:

```
cd /path/to/my/manage.py/
exec gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.my_settings app.wsgi
```

This works when I execute it with `./filename`

However when I use this

```
 PATH=/path/to/my/manage.py/
 cd $PATH
 exec gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.my_settings app.wsgi
```

it doesn't. the error is

> exec: gunicorn: not found

Isn't that how variables work?

Comment: `PATH` is a variable that has a very specific meaning to your shell, and you've just overwritten it with a value that doesn't meet the expected criteria. You probably ought to at least read `man bash` once... Then use a different variable name than `PATH`...

Comment: true, thanks! can you post is as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"PATH" is probably one of the worst choices you can make for a variable name within `bash` (or indeed most shells), as it provides a list of directories where the shell will search for other external commands (such as `gunicorn`) when needed.

You need to pick a different variable name for your usage. Also note there's a common convention that variables that are for use strictly within your script (called "shell variables") generally use lower case names, while variables that are intended for other external commands to access ("environment variables", distinguished by the fact that you `export` them) use upper case names. It's not a strict requirement, nor will it cause things to fail (at least as long as you don't use a name that hides a built-in meaning for your shell), but many will recommend that you stick to that convention.

Comment: Thanks, works! I used `django_path` instead of `PATH`